# Is My Tent map code is correct or not

Tags: matlab

%here is the link for the explanation of tent map http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tent_map

```
 %hi am new to mat lab and i want know is the code is right for tent map
    %the given equation is ![TENT MAP][1]
    u = 1.99;
    N = 100;
    x(1)=0.5;

    for ii=1:N
        if x(ii) < 0.5 %and condition
            x(ii+1)=u*x(ii); %is it right
        else
            if x(ii) >= 0.5 %and this condition 
            x(ii+1)=u*(1-x(ii)); %is it right
            end
        end
    end


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qz6wh.png
```

Comment: you can verify for yourself if this is right by simply calling `plot(x)`. If the resulting shape is a 'tent' shape, your code is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Although your formulae are technically correct, you will not get the expected plot if you were to plot this function. The reason is that you increment along the x-axis in steps of 1 (in the for loop), and the width of the entire tent map function from the link you provided is 1. Therefore, only the first 2 points in your function are useful. You can remedy this by setting a different step size for the x direction:

```
u = 1.99;
N = 100;
x = linspace(0,1,N);    % create a vector of x-positions

for ii=1:N
    if x(ii) < 0.5 
        y(ii)=u*x(ii); 
    elseif x(ii) >= 0.5
        y(ii)=u*(1-x(ii)); 
    end
end

plot(x,y)
```

But you can make it even simpler using this much shorter code: (which is the non-recursive formula mentioned at the start of the wikipedia article):

```
N = 100;
x = linspace(0,1,N);
u = 2;

y = u*min(x,(1-x));

plot(x,y)
```